# Fill a View with two subviews verically in React Native

Tags: flexbox, react-native

I have a `View` of the following form:

```
    <View ref='parentView' style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Image/>                        
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <View ref='topView'/>
      <View ref='bottomView'/>
    </View>
```

TopView and BottomView should fill ParentView, but with
both having the style `flex: 1`, they each only take up the
space for some text inside them. How do I force these views to fill
their parent height-wise, 50/50?

Comment: Can you post a more complete code sample? What you have should work, but it would be nice to see your style definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a flex 1 on the container, then in the views you want to equally fill the parent with, you also need to set an equal flex property, for example flex:1 on the two child views that you want to expand to fill the parent. I've set up a  working example with your code [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/MgHtTw). The code I used is also below for reference.

https://rnplay.org/apps/MgHtTw

```
<View ref='parentView' style={{flex: 1}}>

    <TouchableOpacity underlayColor="#ededed" style={{backgroundColor: "#ddd",height:50}}>
        <Text style={{textAlign:'center', fontSize:20, marginTop:17}}>Button</Text>        
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
        <View ref='topView'/>
    </View>

    <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
        <View ref='bottomView'/>
    </View>

</View>
```